# While using webview in Xcode, application does not return to the main login destination page

Tags: ios, xcode

While using web view to convert my webpage to an app using Xcode the login button does not return to the designated page after login it kind of stays stuck in the login page(The behaviours works okay in a browser though)

Similar behaviour has been observed whenever there is a return to a different page

This is for making my website accessible as an iOS app using web view

I tried using this code snippet:

var backNavigation: WKNavigation?

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    if backNavigation?.isEqual(navigation) ?? false {
        webView.reload()
        backNavigation = nil}
```

The idea is to allow the application get redirected to the correct page as in the website after login or say cancellation. (The functionality works ok on the website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution might be to Allow Arbitrary Loads to yes under app transport security settings. kindly check the link below:

[Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Answer (score 0):

try adding this code

```
let preferences = WKPreferences()
preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.preferences = preferences
let webview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
```

Comment: @ Deepak Verma: issue remains :(